# Java equals ordo value

Tags: java

What is the Ordo for a java equals method? We dont know what type the objects that are being compared are. Does it make it a O(1) because its constant time for comparing object?

example:
X.equals(Y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It completely depends on the type of the object.  An object with `N` relevant sub-data will be `O(N)`.

For example, `List.equals()` is `O(n)` where `n = size()`.  However, if each element of the list is a list of size `m`, then it will be `O(n*m)`.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on the object. If `equals` isn't overridden, though, it should be O(1).

(Ordo?)

Comment: "Ordo" is a Latin word for "Order".

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as asking about the 'Ordo' of an abstract method.

However, if the time needed to compare two objects is not dependent on the input size (n), this would be O(1).